# How to hide the URL of the embedded website in Wix.com?

Tags: velo

I have built a website on wix.com and embed my existed website on AWS in the web pages of Wix.

However, the users can find the URL of the embedded website from the 'View source' function of the web browser client. Is there any way to hide the URL in the HTML of the webpage?
Alternatively, is there any way to let the user sign once using the same user name and password to login to both my website on Wix.com and my website on AWS?

Thank you.

Comment: The first one is not possible. The second is not possible the exact way you described but it might possible to achieve the same foal in a different way. Can you elaborate about the use case? Why do you want to hide the URL?

Comment: Because I want to embed some charged video link and web service in my Wix website. I don't want the users to know the direct URL, so they can download without subscription.

Comment: Got you. Another question. Is the app in the iframe  open? Can you change its code? Or is it a closed product you can only use as is? The reason I ask this because if you can make the app making server calls (to the Wix site), then it might be possible

Comment: Yes. I can change the code of app. I think it is in the iframe open. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand whay do you meam by `it is in the iframe open`. Anyway the idea is to have a database in the wix site with columns of userId (the wix user) and a token - which will be generated for every login. When you render the iframe, you can pass the token via the iframe url or by `postEvent`. When the app gets the token it send an ajax call to the website to validate to token. This call will be handled by `http-function` and will check in the tokens database if the token is valid. This how you can know that the user is logged in.

Comment: You can skip the token and just pass the userId but it's more secured with the token in my opinion. It's not a trivial solution, I know so if something is not clear, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I can understand the idea, but cannot find a good way to realize it. I am currently learning from this document: https://support.wix.com/en/article/using-oauth-sso-with-velo. I think it is similar to your idea but using google SSO service. If could, would you like to recommend some tutorials about this solution? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I don't know about such a tutorial. I basically made it in my mind. Maybe there is more officiant way but I'm not that expert at Velo. It will take me time to write a guide for this so here it is in short

Comment: Anyway, the flow is: if the user logged in, you create a random token and store it in the user [`custom fields`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-users-backend/updateuserfields) then pass it to the iframe either by query param or by using [`postMessage`](https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-working-with-the-html-iframe-element#messaging-1). In the iframe, you get this random token, send it to the website's server using [http-functions](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-http-functions). This function basically retrieve the user's custom params and check if the token is right.

Comment: You should probably send the `userId` which you can get from https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-users-backend/currentuser.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Mosh, I am working on it. I will update it if I solve the problem.

Comment: That will be great. I look forward to hearing from you